# One query many resuls

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL table that gets 3 columns (for this example):

```
datetimestamp,             value,       var_name
"2020-02-04 16:42:38.711"   "243.70"    ".var_19.VALUE"
"2020-02-04 16:42:38.186"   "243.00"    ".valor_20"
"2020-02-04 16:42:36.92"    "241.70"    ".valor_20"
"2020-02-04 16:42:36.192"   "241.70"    ".var_19.VALUE"
"2020-02-04 16:42:35.669"   "242.20"    ".valor_20"
"2020-02-04 16:42:33.009"   "242.60"    ".valor_20"
"2020-02-04 16:42:31.756"   "243.70"    ".valor_20"
"2020-02-04 16:42:30.956"   "244.30"    ".var_19.VALUE"
"2020-02-04 16:42:30.956"   "-82.05"    ".var_13.VALUE"
"2020-02-04 16:42:30.489"   "243.80"    ".valor_20"
"2020-02-04 16:42:30.489"   "-82.05"    ".valor_15"
"2020-02-04 16:42:29.104"   "-82.15"    ".valor_15"
"2020-02-04 16:42:29.104"   "242.10"    ".valor_20"
"2020-02-04 16:42:29.104"   "0.55"      ".valor_16"
"2020-02-04 16:42:28.045"   "242.60"    ".var_19.VALUE"
"2020-02-04 16:42:28.045"   "-97.45"    ".var_8.VALUE"
"2020-02-04 16:42:27.524"   "242.90"    ".valor_20"
"2020-02-04 16:42:26.266"   "244.60"    ".valor_20"
"2020-02-04 16:42:24.494"   "-116.75"   "valor_15"
"2020-02-04 16:42:24.494"   "388.70"    "valor_20"
```

I would like a query that would return ONE ROW ONLY the last values for all variables I could query; Like this:

Query the last value of:
.valor_20, 
.var_13.VALUE,
.var_8.VALUE

and the result was a return with something like this:
243.00, -82.05, -97.45

How can I achieve this with MySQL?
Thank you

Comment: I am going to reword this to ensure i understand the problem.  Given a list of 3 variable names, get the most recent value for each based on the timestamp, in 1 query.   Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Fallenreaper That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can group your values by **var_name**, and just bring the most recent one with the *MAX()* function:

```
SELECT MAX(datetimestamp) as max_date, value, var_name  
FROM your_table
GROUP BY var_name
```

If you want only one row from all **var_name** you can:

```
SELECT datetimestamp, value, var_name 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY value, var_name  
ORDER BY datetimestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: When you have normal columns and aggregate function in select, the `GROUP BY` should list all the normal column in order it to be a correct use of `GROUP BY`. In this case that would be  `GROUP BY value, var_name`. And add `ORDER BY max_time desc LIMIT 1` to the qeury and you have a correct answer.